# In a bash/zsh function how do I do something, then depending on the output, do A or B?

Tags: bash, scripting, zsh, function

This function looks through each local git repository in folder `~/src`, and does `git pull` on it. More and more I keep getting an error

```
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

that requires me to run `git reset --hard` to fix, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to run that command depending on `git pull`'s output, where if I get the above message, to run `git reset --hard`, and if not, to continue on like normal.

The current, semi-working, function is:

```bsh
updatesrc() {
  for i in */.git;
    do (
     echo $i;
     cd $i/..;
     git pull;
    );
  done
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have the tags for both `bash` and `zsh`, but there are relevant syntax and functionality differences between these two. Please focus on one so that a definitive answer can be given.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```bsh
local_changes=$(git status -s)
if [[ -n "$local_changes" ]]; then
    git reset --hard
fi
```

I'm sure there's a more appropriate git subcommand.

But if you don't care about local changes at all, then do the reset unconditionally.

```bsh
git reset --hard
git pull
```